# Windows 10 is deleting me out of local administrators group constantly

Tags: windows-10, security, administrator, local, microsoft

**Problem:**

Windows 10 suddenly keeps removing local machine administrator rights from everyone except the disabled built-in administrator account, which luckily I was able to regain control with.

**Machine Info:**

Win10Pro at home, not on a domain

**Local admins wanted:**

All accounts. I used to just add all my accounts manually, but also authenticated users group would do fine.

**What Windows is doing:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCkB.png (Removed authenticated users, terminating admin rights for all)

**Steps taken:**

Looked into rsop.msc and secpool.msc for any possible group policy type settings, but could not find any. I turn off Windows Defender in favor of ESET, nothing else special on the machine. I created a batch to constantly check every 1 second and immediately tell me when I'm dropped out of admin rights. That lead me to the image I posted. I am doing nothing in particular everytime this happens. I thought maybe this has to do with no longer running as a local account (M$ wants you to sign into an account and auto-ties you when you use their services, thanks M$). I signed out and ran my checker again, still getting reset.

The strange thing is it forces two accounts that are ? marks in the administrators group. There are not .bak accounts in registry signaling corrupt accounts and I have run SFC/CHKDSK just to make sure I have no corruptions going on. I searched them both in an advanced registry searcher to find that both of them are only defined in one spot... the backend default ACL for the local Administrators group (as I understand it):

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\Providers\C265A0F4-1D1E-47F6-A1AD-C5E571620175\default\Device\LocalUsersAndGroups

Using this I found this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-localusersandgroups ... so I tried setting group action to "U" for update, adding main account in and pushing it to the registry key, only to come back later and see it was reverted to exactly how it was.

My only thought is that maybe some aggressive policy from work has somehow invaded its way down into my local machine, but I have no idea how if so.

I've never had this issue in all my years and it is driving me bananas. :) and no, I don't want to reformat... I will make a script to keep overwriting permissions if that is what it comes down to. Frickin Windows 10.

Edit: I've discovered whatever it is ran at 11:26AM two days in a row now. There is nothing in task scheduler to explain it. I may end up watching all processes on computer at this time to see if I can figure it out...

Comment: @LPChip - I read that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what happened is I logged into O365 apps at home using my work license and that tied my home machine to work. Despite not being on the domain, this put my device under Microsoft Intune management. At work we must have set a policy to empty out the local administrator group. This is a video of pretty much exactly what I saw here: https://youtu.be/rDzHJwG-Vjk?t=2464

Again, this won't show up as any local computer policies. However, in registry when I searched the ? keys I did find they were filed under PolicyManager and articles relating to Policy CSP. As you can see in the video, there it is.

How to fix? Well typing "your info" in start and looking at accounts you will probably see it with just "manage" and no remove ability, because you are enrolled to MS Intune and the junk is inside your machine.

See:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/unenroll-your-device-from-intune-windows

There is a special intune portal that doesn't show on your O365 account page. Don't hit disable there, it says it will lockup the machine...

https://portal.manage.microsoft.com/devices

Here you should be able to sign in and manage it on your end, just remove device. Otherwise, talk to your company's administrator about it.